# How to set target folder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I set the root folder in JavaScript when using Ajax?

This is my code?

```
var url="../../ajax_permission_data.php"

url=url+"?opp="+operation+"&userid="+userId;

url=url+"&sid="+Math.random()
```

But I am getting error file not found. If I am putting  this file in same folder then it will work. But I don't want to all the files in same folder. So please help me how to set the path.

Comment: You should probably use absolute URLs (`/path/to/ajax_permission_data.php` instead of `../../ajax_permission_data.php`) if you want the same snippet of code to just work regardless of the folder you place it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var path="http://www.mysite.com/";

    var url=path+"folder/ajax_permission_data.php";

    url=url+"?opp="+operation+"&userid="+userId;

    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
```